# API Gateway serverless Lambda integration "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless to deploy my API, using the lambda integration, and I am getting the error "Unsupported Media Type". I am doing something wrong here, but not sure what. If I set it up manually in the AWS console, it works just fine, but I want to do it in serverless. Below is a snippet from my serverless.yml, a screenshot of what I want it to look like after deploy, and a screenshot of what it currently looks like with my serverless.yml as it is.

```
    events:
  - http:
      path: /path
      method: post
      integration: lambda
```

**What Integration Response & Method Response currently look like in AWS console:**

[image]

**What I want them to look like:**

[image]

Basically, the Integration Response HTTP status Pattern and Method Response Models need to be included in the serverless.yml, but I have yet to find the correct configuration. They are not included in my example at all, as I did not know which failing example to put in. The [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#pass-through-behavior) make it look fairly straight forward yet I have failed to get the result I want with all of my attempts so far.